# WIFI debugging with MI Box s in Linux (Ubuntu). Device not recognized

Tags: linux, android-studio, ubuntu, android-tv, xiaomi

I am trying to debug via WIFI using a MI Box S device in Ubuntu 20.04/Android studio.

I have been successful doing this in Windows 10 (but would rathe develop in Linux)
I have been successful doing this with other devices (Android phones/tv boxes)

I have followed all the instructions on setting thins up with adb

The problem is that the device is not being seen by the system

lsusb does not list it

I've added the following line to /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android-rules

SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="2717", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"

Nothing seems to work.

Is there something I'm missing? a Driver, Some configuration?

Thanks in advance